# git rename vs delete duplicate heuristic

Tags: git, version-control, delete-file, file-rename, dvcs

Suppose I rename a file from `a.txt` to `b.txt`.  Git detects this properly; very nice.
Here's a trickier case.  I have two IDENTICAL files, `x.txt` and `y.txt`.  I want to de-dupe them and call the result `z.txt`.  Git reports one rename and one deletion.  The question is, WHICH file gets renamed, and which gets deleted?  Who cares, they're the same, right?  But only the one that's renamed gets its history preserved, and I do have preferences there.

Comment: As always with these questions: any detection for renames is *purely* a user-facing facility  to help understand commits. For git itself it doesn't matter: it simply has a new commit with some files and their respective content. No renaming-detection is necessary (or even helpful) for git itself.

Comment: sure but it helps ME.  I still want to be able to git blame and get the "right" answer

Comment: After some tests, I think git sorts the file names ascendingly and then appoints the first file as the renamed source and the rest as the deleted.

Comment: That matches what I've been seeing, but I did not notice the pattern until you pointed it out.  Thank you!

Comment: So I guess that means that there's no way to do what I want unless I split this change into two commits.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a preference, don't rely on git's deduping. Explicitly rename the one you want using `git mv x.txt z.txt` and delete the other using `git rm y.txt`. Note: this assumes you want to preserve `x.txt`'s history. If you want to preserve `y.txt`'s history, swap `x.txt` and `y.txt` in the aforementioned commands.

Comment: Will this actually make any difference in the created commit? Since the resulting files are identical, I don't believe git has a way to store the difference in the commit.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't make a difference. Git doesn't care *how* the files in the commit were added, deleted, renamed.

Answer (score 0):

This is *hackish* but it can be solved by tricking git itself by doing a rename on a separate branch and *forcing* git to keep both files on a merge.

```
git checkout -b rename-branch
git mv a.txt b.txt
git commit -m "Renaming file"
# if you did a git blame of b.txt, it would _follow_ a.txt history, right?
git checkout main
git merge --no-ff --no-commit rename-branch
git checkout HEAD -- a.txt # get the file back
git commit -m "Not really renaming file"
```

With a straight copy, you get this:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --name-status
* 70f03aa (HEAD -> master) COpying file straight
| A     new_file.txt
* efc04f3 (first) First commit for file
  A     hello_world.txt
$ git blame -s new_file.txt
70f03aab 1) I am here
70f03aab 2) 
70f03aab 3) Yes I am
$ git blame -s hello_world.txt
^efc04f3 1) I am here
^efc04f3 2) 
^efc04f3 3) Yes I am
```

Using the rename on the side and getting the file back you get:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph master2 --name-status
*   30b76ab (HEAD, master2) Not really renaming
|\  
| * 652921f Renaming file
|/  
|   R100        hello_world.txt new_file.txt
* efc04f3 (first) First commit for file
  A     hello_world.txt
$ git blame -s new_file.txt
^efc04f3 hello_world.txt 1) I am here
^efc04f3 hello_world.txt 2) 
^efc04f3 hello_world.txt 3) Yes I am
$ git blame -s hello_world.txt
^efc04f3 1) I am here
^efc04f3 2) 
^efc04f3 3) Yes I am
```

Rationale is that if you want to see history of the *original* file git will do it without issues.... if you want to do it on the *copy*, then git will follow the separate branch where the rename is and then it will be able to jump to the original file following the *copy*, just because it's done on *that* branch.

Comment: I think you misread my question, or maybe I wrote it unclearly.  You just posted a very good answer to a problem I have indeed faced in the past.  But it's not the one I face now.  You explained how to COPY a file while preserving history.  Whereas I want to DELETE multiple identical files and "consolidate" them into a new file with a new name.  (but same contents).  The trick is to ensure that I get to control WHICH file gets counted as "renamed" and which get counted as deleted.